# How to skip login screen on Lubuntu (17.04) - Lxqt

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, auto-login, lxqt

I just installed Lubuntu 17.04, and am testing out the not-officially-released LXQT window system for it. Everything seems to work great so far, aside from a few little bugs; the only one that really bothers me is that I can't seem to figure out how to set it to skip the login screen. I have edited the lightdm.conf every which way to no avail. Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I was having trouble because LXQt is not using lightdm to login, it is using SDDM, so I created a configuration file at /etc/sddm.conf:

```
nano /etc/sddm.conf
```

and added the following text to it:

```
[Autologin]
User=username
Session=lxqt.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for the correct file to edit, because I don't have the files, that are mentioned in other explanations, but I have a sddm.conf - that solved it for me :)

Comment: I don't have this file (Ubibtu 22.04). Where could it be instead?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough try opening terminal and putting `sudo visudo` then enter your password, find the line that says `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` and change it to `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`